# Do tag RSS feeds attract many viewers?

Tags: support, feed, tag-bubble

Do we have any statistics giving an idea of how many people follow new questions on tags via RSS feeds?  We have some sort of a proxy for this information via the number of followers shown in the tag-bubble, but this feature is, I guess, probably not used so much by somewhat casual vistors to SX sites, while looking for RSS feeds is a pretty well-established behaviour.

I ask this following the discussion of an answer I gave to a question, [Do we want discipline-specific tags?](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1323/do-we-want-discipline-specific-tags) about the value of tags for professional specialisations on tex.sx,